# SQL OR Operator

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm currently fiddling with [O'Reilly's Learning SQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007270). Given the the following query, it returns 21 rows:

```
select account_id, product_cd, cust_id, avail_balance 
from account 
where 
product_cd = 'CHK' OR 
product_cd = 'SAV' OR 
product_cd = 'CD'  OR 
product_cd = 'MM'
```

Being used to BPFs I tried this, which returns 24 rows and 96 Warnings.

```
select account_id, product_cd, cust_id, avail_balance
from account
where product_cd = ('CHK' OR 'SAV' OR 'CD' OR 'MM');
```

I know, one could use the `IN` operator but, why does the second
query return 3 more rows?

Comment: What SQL database are you using? This syntax is not valid on some of them.

Comment: Suggest sticking with the ANSI standard `IN`.

Comment: very obscure question. I thought I didn't know something about SQL. Next time you write such a question, at least write what's the output, instead of its size.

Comment: Hi,

yes it's mysql. thanks for the fast answers. can't vote yet :/

Kind regards

Heinz

Comment: I've merged your two unregistered accounts. You should be able to comment / accept an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that there is some implicit conversion involved and `('CHK' OR 'SAV' OR 'CD' OR 'MM')` is being evaluated as a boolean. This does not seem valid on SQL Server, e.g., I cannot do:

```
select ('CHK' OR 'SAV' OR 'CD' OR 'MM')
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is MySql, I think you will find that your second query is returning a result equivilent to 'where product_cd = 1' which just so happens to be 3 more rows then the first query, the second query isn't correct

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning SQL, i.e. ANSI SQL, you should set MySQL to use ANSI confomance, or use a really ANSI conformant product that catches your errors and doesn't return psuedo-results. The expression below:

```
('CHK' OR 'SAV' OR 'CD' OR 'MM')
```

is plain error in SQL, as OR can only be used with boolean values, for example the result of a comparison.

MySQL is "converting" the strings into integers and suchlike, then comparing the result of the expression with the product_cd. The result of the query is useless.